# using a receipt printer

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I am developing an application in which one of the module is receipt printing.
I have coded for the printer, but when I execute the program I get an exception in one of my method. Here is the code where I am getting the exception.

Printer: PMX Thermal Receipt Printer
Model: PMX 80220

```
private PosPrinter GetReceiptPrinter()
{
    PosExplorer posExplorer = new PosExplorer(this);                 
    DeviceInfo receiptPrinterDevice = posExplorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter, "MYPRINTER");
    return (PosPrinter)posExplorer.CreateInstance(receiptPrinterDevice); //Here I am getting an exception "ArgumentNullException"        
}
```

Comment: do a test to see if receiptPrinterDevice == null, it may not be getting the device with posExplorer.GetDevice

Comment: Make sure that "MYPRINTER" is the actual name of the installed printer  in 'Devices and Printers'

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this line here `DeviceInfo receiptPrinterDevice = posExplorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter, "MYPRINTER");` is returning a null. Ensure that his line is actually returning DeviceInfo.